# Selective caching - by user

Tags: theming, caching

Is it even possible to do this?

The goal is to group our visitors:

```
Group A sees Theme A
Group B sees Theme B
```

I am able to achieve this goal through cookies. But when caching is enabled (i.e. Site config > Performance > On), things are messed up. This is what happens:

1) Group A visits Page-1
-- Page-1 is not cached yet.
-- Cookies are properly checked.
-- Page-1 is displayed using Theme A

2) Group B visits Page-2
-- Page-2 is not yet cached.
-- Cookies are properly checked.
-- Page-2 is displayed using Theme B

3) Group A visits Page-2
-- Page-2 is already cached.
-- Cookies are ignored
-- Page-2 is displayed using Theme B (when it should be displayed using Theme A)

So now what I am thinking is, instead of using cookies, I'll use separate cache for each group.

Is this even possible? :S If not, any recommendations are welcome.

Inputs will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by group ? Organic Group or Group of users ?

Comment: visitors are randomly selected if they are gonna be under group A or B, or no group at all

Comment: just out of curiosity, does using the [cache_clear_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/6) function help.. though it might beat the purpose of enabling caching in your case to me it appears it could solve the problem though in an inefficient manner...

Comment: Hi optimus. It will, but I will have to run that code on every page, which is almost the same as disabling caching.

Comment: So you're just looking for a method to perform A/B testing?

Comment: @Chapabu: Sort of. Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here's what I did.

I extended drupal's cache.inc by including this line on settings.php

```
$conf['cache_inc'] = sites/all/modules/mycustom_module/my_custom_cache.inc';
```

I basically copied drupal's cache.inc and pasted it in my module's folder, renamed it, and then added a few lines of code where I altered how $cid's are generated. This way I am able to create $cid variants of cache depending on the theme

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Cache page based on cookie value and URL](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9093/cache-page-based-on-cookie-value-and-url)

Long story short what you want can be done. Depends on how you want to do it :)